# Rotate as well as resize duplicated objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I want to achieve a pattern around a circle. Consider the petals of a flower. I want to repeat the petal around the circle's center, with gradually increasing size. The increase in the size would be radially outwards. It is quite easily achieved in Photoshop, but I'm facing problems in replicating the same over in Illustrator.

Please, can anyone let me know how to do the above? 
In positive anticipation, many thanks!

Comment: Hi RKB, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: There are plenty of people here who will help you. We are all friendly, and rules are in place to make sure we all get treated the same. Some users may not understand that, but I don't see any of their answers below, so I would take their advice with a grain of salt. A quick google search would have most definitely helped you out with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is rather easy in Illustrator. This is one of the possible methods:

1. Select your first petal with the black arrow selection tool (<kbd>V</kbd>);
2. Select <kbd>Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform...</kbd>;
3. Set the number of copies to your desired amount of petals and check the 'preview' box;
4. Set a value slightly above 100% for both Horizontal and Vertical scale;
5. Set a value for the angle, eg. 10°;
6. Play around with the 'Move' values until your copies line up nicely the way you want them to.

Since this produces an effect on a single object, you can still edit the original petal (and that one only), and all others will follow suit. In case you'd want to manipulate the petals separately, you'll have to <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> first, turning all copies into separate objects.

Comment: How does he then get them to rotate around the circle with their inside edges all at the same distance from the centre?

Comment: @Confused Read step 6.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common technique in Illustrator called "Step and Repeat".

The trick is to transform an object once using the "Transform Each" option, making sure to hit "Copy" instead of just hitting "Ok". Then you use the "Transform Again" option to repeat your procedure over and over for each consecutive object.

This technique is broken down into detail with this tutorial:
http://www.ehow.com/how_4430827_step-repeat-illustrator.html